# how can i Copy Into from more than one Table ?? Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

with this line i will get the data2016 but what if i have a multiple years data (2017, 2018, 2019 ...) how can write the statment

```
COPY INTO "DATA_HUB_DEV"."STAGE"."mytable" ("/BIC/ZDBTVABIS") FROM (SELECT $1:"/BIC/ZDBTVABIS" FROM  @STAGE_DATA_LAKE_RAW/data2016);
```

- file format = parquet
- Snowflake
- beginner

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are all in a different folder under your stage, you could simply remove the folder from your stage path and use a PATTERN to grab the files underneath it.

There are some good examples in the documentation link here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching